"Unknown method: Not implemented yet for find" in Flutter app automation using appium webdriverIO
For Flutter app, we are using

appium-flutter-finder and appium-flutter-driver
webdriverIO framework using Typescript

Scenario:

Login page: Username and password, click on login button
Redirected to home page and a dialog is displayed where the user need to click on option Got it!

Issue:

During the execution, I'm able to see the dialog with the Got it! option but the option is not clicked
To click on the option, using the below logic:

const gotITButtonLocator = byText('Got it!');
const element = driver.$(gotITButtonLocator);
await element.click();

Terminal logs:
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 405 due to unknown method: Not implemented yet for find.
[0-0] unknown method in "My Driver Dashboard.should login with valid credentials and Click on Got it"
unknown method: Not implemented yet for find.
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/prabhakary/Documents/Ziing/Mobile/VSCODE/mobile-e2e-test/tests
/shared/specs/driver/test_driver.e2e.ts:66:9)

Appium server logs:
[f3380dda][FlutterDriver@bade] Encountered internal error running command:NotImplementedError: Not implemented yet for find.

I kindly requesting for help on this scenario:
import { expect, driver, $ } from "@wdio/globals";
import { selectors } from "../../../../helpers/selectors.ts";
import { pause } from "../../../../helpers/utilities.ts";
import { byText, byValueKey } from "appium-flutter-finder";

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const loginPage = require('../../../shared/pageObjects/login.page.ts');
const env = process.env.TEST_ENV || "demo";
dotenv.config({ path: `env/.env.${env}` });

describe("My Driver Dashboard", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {});

    it("should find and click the OK button", async () => {
        await pause(3000);
        const buttonText = await driver.getElementText(selectors.continueButton);
        if (buttonText === "OK") {
            console.log("OK button is displayed. Clicking the OK button...");
            await driver.elementClick(selectors.continueButton);
        } else {
            console.log("OK button is not displayed.");
        }
    });

    it("should login with valid credentials and Click on Got it", async () => {
        const email = process.env.EMAIL;
        const password = process.env.PASSWORD;

        // Accept the permissions
        await loginPage.loginFlow(email, password);
        console.log('Login completed..Checking for the "Got it" button.');

        await pause(10000);

        // Click the "Got it" button
        const gotITButtonLocator = byText('Got it!');
        await pause(10000);
        console.log('********** "Got it" TEXT. **********', gotITButtonLocator);
        const element = driver.$(gotITButtonLocator);
        await element.click();
        await pause(10000);
    });
});


Below is the source code snippet for flutter


      if (!approvedShowOnce) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const OkCancelPopup(
              popupTitle: DASHBOARD_DIALOG_APPROVED_TITLE,
              popupContent: DASHBOARD_DIALOG_APPROVED_CONTENT,
              okButtonText: DASHBOARD_DIALOG_GOT_BUTTON,
              cancelButtonText: null,
              okHandler: null,
              cancelHandler: null,
            );
          },
        );



The DASHBOARD_DIALOG_GOT_BUTTON ,


const DASHBOARD_DIALOG_GOT_BUTTON = 'Got it!';




Solved. Working fine.
My bad, I reliazed that imports for find  were missing.
After Adding const find = require("appium-flutter-finder") solved the above issue
